# How to make a quick unwinding for spinner by css?

Tags: css, spinner

How to make a spiral unwinding for spinner by css?
For now i have that animation rules:
How am I supposed to change them?

```
@keyframes spinning {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not a very accurate description of an animation.

Comment: You mind specifying your question a bit more precisely?

Please consider sharing your html markup as well.